# react css transition group animate single element

Tags: css, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I am using CSSTransitionGroup from react-transition-group and I have a page displaying several objects, which go through some filters (every filter changes the state of the array - cant do it otherwise). I want to activate leave transition only on one element (when the timer of the object gets to 0).

Is there a way to achieve it without activating the leave when i filter?

**EDIT**:
Each object in my array is an auction that contains several information including a timer. i want to avoid the activation of the leave animation when i search my db and activate it only when the timer finishes.

home component:

```
eachAuction(item, i) {
    return <Auction key={i} index={i} auctionfinished={this.deleteAuction}
            offerBid={this.offerBid} data={item} />
}

render:
<div>
    <CSSTransitionGroup
     transitionName="auction"
     transitionAppear={true}
     transitionAppearTimeout={700}
     transitionEnterTimeout={700}
     transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
     {this.state.auctionsArr.map(this.eachAuction)}
    </CSSTransitionGroup>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] for us.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** What about specify the leaving class inside the element?

```js
eachAuction(item, i) {
  return <Auction {timer===0 ?? 'className="leaving"'} ... />
}
```

Then you specify the CSS effects:

```
.auction-leaving div { display: none }
.auction-leaving div.leaving { /* animation start */ }
.auction-leaving-active div.leaving { /* animation end*/ }
```

Comment: timer is different for each auction and is calculated inside auction component